# How could this be done with multi-threading?

Tags: c#, multithreading

So, I will be reading through an arraylist of users info and doing some task with it.

e.g.,

```
for(int i=0;i<lines.Count();i++){
  new Thread(() =>
        {
        Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;
            
        ...some task over here which would take 4-5 minutes
        
        }).Start();
}
```

The arraylist data would be as such :

> user , info, info
>
> user2, info , info
>
> user3, info , info
>
> user , info , info

As you can see in the 4th line, the 1st user is repeated again.

Now what I want is some way to detect if already a thread is running for a user. Like there would be 2 threads running for user(line 1 and line 4). Which shouldn't happen.

What I have thought of doing is creating an arraylist of all the users whose thread is currently running and check through that arraylist everytime a new thread is created. If so wait for that thread to complete and then start the thread.

But is there any better way to do it?

Comment: Does `lines` contain duplicate for 1st `user`?

Comment: @Dennis not duplicate but some other info to process about 1st user.

Answer (score 8):

```
Parallel.ForEach(lines.GroupBy(line => line.TheUser), grp => {
    // processing user grp.Key
    foreach(var line in grp) {
        // do the stuff here
    }
});
```

Comment: But how can I access the groups seperately?
Like, How can I run group 1 into one thread, group 2 into another thread, group 3 into another thread...

Comment: @SidharthJain that is exactly what `Parallel.ForEach` does, but with sanity (not opening a silly number of threads, for example)

Comment: @SidharthJain please tell me what exactly you are objecting to? You asked me how you would get them onto threads, and I explained that this is what the `Parallel.ForEach` did. Nothing more, nothing less. You are out of line. If you think I was attacking you somehow: that is entirely in your imagination.

Answer (score 0):

In your loop, simply copy the item to a new variable (to solve to closure issue) and pass it to the thread.

```
        ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
        foreach (var item in al)
        {
            **var obj = item;**
            new Thread(() =>
                       {
                           Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;

                           //...some task over here which would take 4 - 5 minutes

                       }).Start(**obj**);
        }
```

Comment: The problem is not about closure, it is about the array containing items for the same user, and the OP wants to check if a running thread already exists for that user.