# Separate List into groups

Tags: c#, multithreading

I posted a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34129085/how-could-this-be-done-with-multi-threading)

and got [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34129204/4305977)

```
Parallel.ForEach(lines.GroupBy(line => line.TheUser), grp => {
// processing user grp.Key
foreach(var line in grp) {
    // do the stuff here
}
});
```

How can I access the groups of user 1 or user 2 separately instead of a foreach?

In the above code it is sorting and printing them all. I want to access them group wise.

Comment: You need to be a little clearer as to what you actually want to do. What does *I want to access them group wise* mean? What do you want to do on the grouping?

Answer (score 1):

```
lines.AsParallel().Select(x => x.TheUser)
```

should return you an IEnumrable of TheUser ...

Answer (score 0):

You really should use Microsoft's Reactive Framework for this. Just NuGet "Rx-Main" and then you can do this:

```
var query =
    from grp in lines.GroupBy(line => line.TheUser).ToObservable()
    from line in grp.ToObservable()
    from output in Observable.Start(() => /* Do lengthy process here */)
    select new { line, output };

query.Subscribe(result => { /* get the results here */ });
```

Now, just so that I can show that this works:

```
var query =
    from grp in Enumerable.Range(0, 20).GroupBy(x => x % 5).ToObservable()
    from line in grp.ToObservable()
    from tid in Observable.Start(() => System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)
    select new { line, tid };
```

When run with `query.Subscribe(x => { ... })` it gives this kind of output:

[image: results]

You can see that the `ManagedThreadId` changes for the input values and thus the processing happens in parallel.